# how do I load an image in a picture box of another form using open file dialog

Tags: c#

When I click on the linklabel it should open a dialog which a JPEG image file can be chosen, then opens in a picture box of another form.

This is the code I have so far:

```
private void llblOpenSavedImages_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
    if (ofd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) 
    {
        Open_Saved_Design_Form frm = new Open_Saved_Design_Form();
        frm.Show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Form 1:

```
private void linkLabel1_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
    if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dlg.FileName))
        {
            Form2 frm = new Form2(dlg.FileName);
            frm.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

Form 2:

```
private string _imagePath;

public Form2(string imagePath)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _imagePath = imagePath;
}

private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox1.ImageLocation = _imagePath;
}
```

Comment: I have no errors with this but when I click the link nothing happens

Comment: Are u linking the event linkLabel1_LinkClicked to the label click ?

Comment: Yes that is the event itself.

Comment: Double click on the linklabel and paste the code from forms 1 inside it. The linkclicked event should be following linkLabel1_LinkClicked if u use the same code i gave u

Comment: I did that it is't working, and I would like to load any image not just 1.

Comment: Linking events, passing parameters such is basic knowledge. the code i gave u works. Look at your code, u missed something somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Just pass your image path to your another form constructor like this:

```
 Open_Saved_Design_Form frm = new Open_Saved_Design_Form();
 frm.Show(ofd.FileName);
```

And in your `Open_Saved_Design_Form` add a constructor

```
private string imgPath;
public Open_Saved_Design_Form(string path)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    imgPath = path;
}
```

Then you can use that path in your second form.

Comment: I have an error with the second line of the constructor. frm.show(ofd.filename);

Answer (score 1):

You would need to pass the file name from the OpenFileDialog to the new form like so:

```
private void llblOpenSavedImages_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
    if (ofd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) 
    {
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ofd.FileName))
        {
            Open_Saved_Design_Form frm = new Open_Saved_Design_Form(ofd.FileName);
            frm.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

Your second form's contructor should look like this:

```
private string fileName;

public Open_Saved_Design_Form(string file)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    fileName = file;
}
```

Then in your new form's Load event, you would set the image:

```
private void Open_Saved_Design_Form_Load(Object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    pictureBox.ImageLocation = fileName;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but in the load event I have an error with the filename

Comment: Also I would like to load any image not just 1.

Comment: You need to update your constructor to accept one argument of type string and then set the private field, fileName, to the value of the input argument like I have shown.